# Generate a data-structure visualisation from JSON object to indicate get an overview of objects and relations

Tags: json, data-structures

I would like to generate an SVG/PNG to visualise the data structure of a JSON object. I used to do this online generating images like in the file attached.

I cannot find the source where I generated these files anymore and using google I cannot find anything comparable.

Any pointers are massively appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON Crack makes graphs similar to this. You can upload your JSON file and the graph is generated for you. You can then navigate around a canvas to see the relationships between the key value pairs of the JSON file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is close enough to what I was looking for. Thank you.